# Extract upper diagonal of a block matrix in numpy - like np.triu_idx, but for block matrices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, pytorch

I want to extract off-block-diagonal elements from a block-diagonal matrix, i.e.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

A = np.array([
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [1, 1, 1]
])

B = np.array([
    [2, 2],
    [2, 2]
])

C = np.array([
    [3]
])

D = sp.linalg.block_diag(A, B, C)
print(D)

>>> array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]])
```

So, I need to extract the elements over the diagonal that do not belong to blocks, i.e. that ones which are zeros in `D`.

How to achieve that?

Comment: What is the expected output? All elements on the diagonal are non-zero...

Comment: indices of those elements of `D` which 1) do not belong to blocks, 2) are above the diagonal

Comment: Set everything below the diagonal to 1 (or some nonzero).  One of the `tri` functions should help.  Then use `np.nonzero` to get the indices of all zeros (i.e. applied the `not(D)`.

Comment: this will not allow me to get indices for the original block matrix `D`, but only for it's upper triangle

Answer (score 0):

A straightforwad solution based on loops, can one make it better avoiding loops?

Taking upper triangle and then taking non-zero values is not what I want as it will not allow me to get indices for the original block matrix D, but only for it's upper triangle.

```
def block_triu_indices(block_sizes=None):
    
    n = np.sum(block_sizes)

    blocks = []
    for block_size in block_sizes:
        blocks.append(np.ones((block_size, block_size)))

    A = sp.linalg.block_diag(*blocks)

    row_idx = []
    col_idx = []

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            if A[i,j]==0:
                row_idx.append(i)
                col_idx.append(j)

    return (np.array(row_idx), np.array(col_idx))
```

```
block_triu_idx = block_triu_indices([3, 2, 1])
print(block_triu_idx)

>>> (array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4]),
     array([3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]))
```

```
print(D[block_triu_idx])

>>> array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```